# php in clause not working for prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, bindparam

I am trying to make a mysql query with a prepared statement including an "IN" clause.
This is the statement:

```
$stmt1 = $c->db->prepare("SELECT ITEM_URL,VIRALITY FROM RSSINGEST WHERE userid=(?) AND ITEM_URL IN (SELECT url FROM person_url WHERE person=(?) AND userid=(?))");
$stmt1->bind_param("sss", $userid,$name,$userid);
```

However I always get the error: "Call to a member function bind_param()..." which occurs when the prepared statement is wrong.

Basically I am trying to find all urls from one user who also has those urls in another table. In this other table called "person_url" every entry has also a "person". I want only those with a special "person" in it, as you can see in the statement.

Maybe somebody can tell me if there is a other way to do this or where the error is?

EDIT 1: userid is a string, they name can be misleading.

EDIT 2: Create Statements for both tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rssingest` (
  `item_id` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `feed_url` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `item_url` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `item_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fetch_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `fb_share` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_like` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_comment` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tw_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pinterest` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linkedin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `googleplus` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stumbleupon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `virality` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userID` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people_url` (
  `person` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `virality` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `insertdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `userID` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

EDIT 3: Full Error

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\monitorUser\websiteBuilder.php** on line **163**

EDIT 4: Tunnel vision at its finest. I have written person_url in the statement instead of people_url. Thanks everybody.

Comment: `userid` isn't an INT?

Comment: no userid is probably a bad name but it is a string

Comment: show us `CREATE TABLE` statement for both tables please

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: `person_url` vs. `people_url`

Comment: The prepare failed...because the table in your code does not match the MySQL structure

Comment: omg I am dying... how could I not see that... thanks a lot!

Comment: When in doubt, echo and output as many errors as the language will allow

Comment: Don't listen to @Alex because I have never seen that syntax before. You are basically telling MySQL to evaluate your strings like math. This is sure to cause headaches later on. Actually listen to only half of what Alex said. Just do `SELECT ITEM_URL,VIRALITY FROM RSSINGEST WHERE userid=? AND ITEM_URL IN (SELECT url FROM person_url WHERE person=? AND userid=?)`. Since you are preparing your statements, the escaping and everything is being taken care of on the DB-side

Comment: @Alex quote placeholders? Why?

Comment: @chris85 you are right! .I just reread doc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  so there is no need even for quotes so just `?`

Answer (score 0):

The query in `$stmt1` should be

```
$stmt1 = $c->db->prepare(
  "SELECT item_url, virality 
  FROM rssingest
  WHERE userid=(?)
  AND item_url IN (SELECT url FROM people_url WHERE person=(?) AND userid=(?))"
);
```